# How to add .net core Web API project to an existing .NET core (3.1) Web Application project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to add **.NET Core Web** API project to an existing **.NET core (3.1)** Web Application project, with JWT Token Authentication with Identity Framework with routing and all..

Please Do we have any suggestion & is this possible & good idea to combine both the Projects?

Comment: Add more description about what you already have and how you want to add API (as an external resource/project or as a part of existing project)

Comment: A .NET Core Web API project *is* a .NET Core Web Application project, one that only has controllers instead of pages or views. Are you asking how to call the API from the Web site perhaps? Or do you want to split one big project into separate ones?

Comment: Hi @DaksheshDave, please clarify more about the actual scenario and question, so that we can understand it better.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here. They are both "web" projects. Are you saying you currently have like an MVC project and you want an API project to act as your backend? You can certainly do this. For example, an MVC project alone is self sufficient as a full stack web project, however, you could have it act just as a client with a separate API project as your backend server. This way your MVC site calls your API. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Its not good idea to add `.NET Core Web API` to an existing `.NET core (3.1) Web Application` project.. first of all you have to set "Default Project" from your solution, and both project have entry point or start up class.
So if you want you can marge both project, you can move your controller and service from `.NET Core Web API` to `.NET core (3.1) Web Application` project, that may large work if your project size is big...

Comment: A .NET Core Web API project *is* a .NET Core Web Application project. There's nothing wrong with splitting one big project into several modules either. There's no need for all projects to have a Startup class, only the main one needs to set up configuration, DI and logging

Comment: I have, it's unclear and could mean two different things. But this answer is simply wrong. Or at least, confusing and unclear as well. There's no reason to put all controllers in the same project. If you use ASP.NET Core Identity, the controllers and UI are in a separate assembly deployed by NuGet